# Writing alter table query inside if statement

Tags: sql, sybase, database-schema, alter-table

I have a table Person which has a column Status. Following code exists in the sqlt file which i am trying to execute

```
if not exists(select 1 from sysobjects, syscolumns where sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id and sysobjects.name = 'Person' and  syscolumns.name = 'Status')

begin

    print "Inside the if statement" 

end


go
```

This works fine and nothing is printed as the table and the column both exist.
If i change the file to following

```
if not exists(select 1 from sysobjects, syscolumns where sysobjects.id = syscolumns.id and sysobjects.name = 'Person' and  syscolumns.name = 'Status')
begin
    print "Inside the if statement"
    alter table Person
    add Status char(5) DEFAULT 'INVLD' NOT NULL
end

go
```

This does not work and i get following error message:

*Msg 2705, Level 16, State 3*

*Server 'NEXUS', Line 6*

*Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'Status' in table
'Person' is specified more than once.*

Why does it go inside if in this code? What is the solution for this?

Comment: The link that you have pointed me to is for sql. I am working with sybase. And i have got to a point where i can make it work, but it doesn't work in a specific case

Answer (score 3):

I know you are not looking for this answer, but here goes: Don't do that.

Reason is, a structure change is part of a general upgrade.  For a given project upgrades happen more than once (like all the time), and usually involve more than one column in more than one table.  Therefore, you make (or use) a tool that just modifies your structure and handle that problem separately from the business logic that is making use of a particular column.